# How to make bar charts with names in abscissa?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm pretty new in R and I have an issue with bar charts.

I would like to create, with ggplot, bar charts where I have in abscissa names (such as "Luke", "Steven" and so on) and in ordinate their age (13, 14...). Nonetheless, I don't understand how to make such graphics because I can' t put in abscissa no-numerical elements. I saw a lot of people use bar charts to make count of a value, such as how many people have black hair, blue eyes... but not so many use bar charts to make a graphic with names (or same value types) in abscissa.

I aim at making a graphic like that : [Example of the desired graphic type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czh0v.png)

I tried this code to solve my issue :

```
age <- c(12, 13, 19, 10)
persons <- c("Luke", "William", "George", "Steven")
df <- data.frame(age, persons)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = persons, y = age)) + geom_bar()
```

But I got this error :

```
Error in `geom_bar()`:
! Problem while computing stat.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `setup_params()`:
! `stat_count()` must only have an x or y aesthetic.
```

I know why I have this error but I don't have the solution of my problem.

If anybody would have an idea, it would be a pleasure!

Comment: Have you tried using `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar()`? The bar variant automatically counts, the column variant takes y-values from data (as you do).

Answer (score 1):

By default `geom_bar` computes the count which is mapped on the `y` (or `x`) aesthetic. That's why you get an error `stat_count() must only have an x or y aesthetic.`. If you want to make a bar chart with both a given `x` and `y` value use `geom_col` or the more verbose `geom_bar(stat="identity")`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = persons, y = age)) + 
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much both of you for your help ! It works and I better understand how geom_bar and geom_col work.